# ionic slide box issue do not show dynamic data from DB (i'm using $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update())

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

i am trying to show a dynamic data on the ionic slide box with ng-repeat. i am using services to get the data from my sqlite DB but i get nothing. i don't know what to do after 3 days with this issue, here is my code:

template.html

```html
<ion-view>
    <ion-nav-title>{{simple.title}}</ion-nav-title>
  <ion-content>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-33 col-offset-33">
            <h1 style="font-size: 72px !important;">{{simple.content}}</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div  class="col">
                <ion-slide-box show-pager="false" does-continue="true">
                    <ion-slide ng-repeat="senci in sencillo">
                       <div class="box">
                           <h1 style="font-size: 52px !important;">{{senci.sound_title}}</h1>

                       </div>
                    </ion-slide>
                </ion-slide-box>

        </div>
      </div>



  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

my service.js

```js
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('DBA', function($cordovaSQLite, $q, $ionicPlatform) {
  var self = this;

  // Handle query's and potential errors
  self.query = function (query, parameters) {
    parameters = parameters || [];
    var q = $q.defer();

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
      $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, parameters)
        .then(function (result) {
          q.resolve(result);
        }, function (error) {
          console.warn('I found an error');
          console.warn(error);
          console.log(error.code + ' / ' + error.message);
          q.reject(error);
        });
    });
    return q.promise;
  };

  // Proces a result set
  self.getAll = function(result) {
    var output = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
      output.push(result.rows.item(i));
    }
    return output;
  };

  // Proces a single result
  self.getById = function(result) {
    var output = null;
    output = angular.copy(result.rows.item(0));
    return output;
  };

  return self;
})
```

```js
.factory('Sounds', function(DBA) {
 var self = this;
 
 
 self.getSimple = function(simpleId) {
    var parameters = [simpleId];
    return DBA.query("SELECT * FROM letters WHERE Id = (?)", parameters)
      .then(function(result) {
        return DBA.getById(result);
      });
  };
  self.getSimpleArr = function(Id) {
    var parameters = [Id];
    return DBA.query("SELECT * FROM words WHERE letter_id = (?)", parameters)
      .then(function(result) {
        return DBA.getById(result);
      });
  };
 
    
  return self;  
    
});
```

controller.js

```js
.controller('SoundsSimpleCtrl', function($scope, Sounds, $stateParams, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate) {
     $scope.sencillo = [];

      $scope.getSimple = function($stateParams) {
        Sounds.getSimple($stateParams.simpleId).then(function(single){
          $scope.simple = single;
          $scope.getArrSimple($scope);
        });
          
      };
      $scope.getArrSimple = function($scope){
          
          Sounds.getSimpleArr($scope.simple.Id).then(function(detalle){
           $scope.sencillo = detalle; 
           $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();
            });
          
      };
      $scope.getSimple($stateParams);
      });
```

i hope you guys can help me, regards.

Comment: Try using ng-if="simple" on the <ion-slide-box> to only show it when the SQLite data has been loaded.

Comment: Hi man, Ok, i will try this one...

Comment: i got the same result man, the slide box still does show nothing, i tried creating a $scope like this `$scope.prueba = [{uno : "uno", dos:"dos"},               {uno : "tres", dos:"cuatro"}];` then i use it with ng-repeat for testing and it works, so i don't know where is the problem...

Comment: how about putting the update() call in $timeout()?

Comment: im sorry man, how can i do this?

Comment: $timeout(function() { $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update() });

Comment: i tried putting  `$timeout(function(){
       $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();
        },5000);` and the problem persist... im going crazy...

Comment: so u r sure the data is coming back from sqlite?

Comment: What is the code for DBA?  Is that using the $cordovaSQLite plugin?

Comment: Man look at this, for testing i tried to put at the begin of my controller this code `$scope.sencillo = [{id : "uno", content:"dos"}, 
                    {id : "tres", content:"cuatro"}];` it means im initializing my $scope.sencillo with that values, so after this my template shows me the slides with those values, so the $scope.sencillo is not updating after the sql sentence is calle, this is my controller updated:...

Comment: `.controller('SoundsSimpleCtrl', function($scope, Sounds, $timeout, $stateParams, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate) { $scope.sencillo = [{id : "uno", content:"dos"}, {id : "tres", content:"cuatro"}]; $scope.getArrSimple = function($scope){ //$scope.simple.Id; Sounds.getSimpleArr($scope.simple.Id).then(function(detalle){ $scope.sencillo = detalle; $timeout(function(){ $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update(); }); //$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update(); }); };`

Comment: Yes, DBA is a main Factory where im using $cordovaSQLite Plugin, it works with my another SQL sentences, this is my first problem.

Comment: now you can see this Factory in the code above...

Comment: can u take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831848/ionic-angularjs-ion-slide-box-with-ng-repeat-not-updating

Comment: i  looked that post before, so thanks, my problem is the slide box does show nothing just a white screen,  even i did a simple sql request and still showing nothing i can´t understand this at all because all my another sql request works well , i tried even this `$scope.sencillo = [{id : "uno", content:"dos"}, {id : "tres", content:"cuatro"}];` at beginning of my controller in that case the slide works so it shows the data, so why doesn't work with the Sql request?

Comment: Hi, i tried to test my SQLite request out of the slide box code and the $scope.sencillo, SHOWS THE DATA, so the problem is inside the slide box   , im going crazy :(

Answer (score 0):

Hi people i resolved my problem, i had a bad SQl Request, im so sorry for be annoying, i just changed to use my service function from getById() to getAll() (these functions are being taken from DBA Factory) like this:

```js
 self.getSimpleArr = function(value) {
    var parameters = [value];
    return DBA.query("SELECT * FROM words WHERE letter_id = (?)",parameters)
        .then(function(result){
          return DBA.getAll(result);
      });
  };
```

the getById() function was returning only the first row of the request, absolutely MY BAD. Regards