# Filtering ng-repeat inside ion-slide-box breaks everything

Tags: angularjs, filter, ionic-framework

I'm using ion-slide to show a list of items as slide pages and now I want to add the feature of filtering that list.

The problem is: when I apply the filter, slide seems to break :(

This is an example of how I am doing this filtering stuff:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myFilter" style="border: 1px solid black;">
  <ion-slide-box>
    <ion-slide ng-repeat="item in items | filter:myFilter">
      <div class="card" style="height: 200px;">
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">{{ item }}</h1>
      </div>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slide-box>
```

And here is a Codepen to show as an example.

http://codepen.io/gbrennon/full/grWxvg/

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to let the slidebox know that the scope variable has been updated, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32123463/3432305).

If you still have problems, try to filter the array manually instead of using the Angular filter and call `$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();` after the array has been updated.