# $ionicModal not updating the content when changes made in the controller when it is open

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an $ionicModal like this:

```
<ion-modal-view>
 <ion-content>
  <ion-slide-box>
    <ion-slide ng-repeat="display in VideoCtrl.display track by $index" >
      <div class="card">
        <div class="item item-divider">
         {{display.start}}-{{display.end}}      
        </div>
        <div ng-style='{ "background" : "#" + display.css.color }'> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slide-box>
 </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

And VideoCtrl is the parent controller of the modal. I am changing the value of 'display' obj in the VideoCtrl and the modal is kept open. But the changes are not reflected on the modal.

How can I bind the changes? I am thinking of ng-model but not getting where to use it and which variable to write.

Comment: I solved it using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831848/ionic-angularjs-ion-slide-box-with-ng-repeat-not-updating)

Answer (score -1):

In your parent controller, when changing a variable, you should wrap it inside $apply fn.

for example:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.display++; // or if display is an object (which I assume from you example), it is still the same.



});
```

Comment: I keep getting that: '$apply is already in progress' by putting $scope.$apply

Comment: Can you share your controller's code?

Comment: Keep in mind that in most places (controllers, services) `$apply` has already been called for you by the directive which is handling the event. An explicit call to `$apply` is needed only when implementing custom event callbacks, or when working with third-party library callbacks.